# Insert Page Break depending on page number

Tags: jasper-reports

I have template, which prints the letters, with variable length and page count. 
They are printing as duplex.

After each letter (A) I add one another document (B), but this have to be printed on new sheet of paper, because customer can this B send back to me.

Because of this I need to insert pagebreak at the end of letter A, but only then, If it ends on page with odd page number.

Is it possible? I think *PrintWhenExpression* is OK, but how should I count the actual page number of pagebreak element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in report variable `PAGE_NUMBER`. To have the page break only if the page number is odd, set the *PrintWhenExpression* to:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} % 2 == 1
```